# Will memory not freed cause segmentation fault in C?

Tags: c, macos, segmentation-fault

I've just encountered a very strange bug. I was doing unit-test for a simple function as below.

UPDATE: Thanks @Bodo, here's the minimal working example. You can simply compile and run `tokenizer.c`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* ============================= BOOL =============================== */
#ifndef _BOOL_
#define _BOOL_

typedef enum {
    true, false
} bool;

#endif // _BOOL_



/* ============================= STACK =============================== */
#ifndef _STACK_
#define _STACK_

typedef void (*stack_freefn)(void *elemAddr);

typedef struct {
    size_t size;                // number of element allowed
    int ite;                    // point to the current last element
    size_t elemSize;            // size of each element (how many bytes)
    void *elems;                // stockage of elements
    stack_freefn freefn;        // free memory allocated for each element if necessary
} stack;

/* constructor */
void new_stack(stack *s, const size_t size, const size_t elemSize, stack_freefn freefn) {
    s->size = size;
    s->ite = 0;
    s->elemSize = elemSize;
    s->elems = malloc(size * elemSize);
    s->freefn = freefn;
}

/* free memory */
void dispose_stack(stack *s) {
    if (s->freefn != NULL) {
        while (s->ite > 0) {
            void *elemAddr = (char *)s->elems + --s->ite * s->elemSize;
            s->freefn(elemAddr);
        }
    }
    free(s->elems);
    s->elems = NULL;
}

/* push one new element on the top */
void push_stack(stack *s, const void *value, const size_t elemSize) {
    if (s->ite == s->size) {
        s->size *= 2;
        s->elems = realloc(s->elems, s->size * s->elemSize);
    }
    void *elemAddr = (char *)s->elems + s->elemSize * s->ite++;
    memcpy(elemAddr, value, s->elemSize);
}

/* pop our the element on the top */
void pop_stack(stack *s, void *res) {
    if (s->ite > 0) {
        void *elemAddr = (char *)s->elems + ((s->ite - 1) * s->elemSize);
        memcpy(res, elemAddr, s->elemSize);
        s->ite--;
    }
}

void clear_stack(stack *s) {
    if (s->freefn != NULL) {
        while (s->ite > 0) {
            void *elemAddr = (char *)s->elems + --s->ite * s->elemSize;
            s->freefn(elemAddr);
        }
    } else {
        s->ite = 0;
    }
}

size_t stack_size(stack *s) {
    return s->ite;
}

#endif // _STACK_



/* ============================= VECTOR =============================== */
#ifndef _VECTOR_
#define _VECTOR_

typedef int (*VectorCompareFunction)(const void *elemAddr1, const void *elemAddr2);

typedef void (*VectorFreeFunction)(void *elemAddr);

typedef struct {
    int elemSize;               //how many byte for each element
    int elemNum;                //number of current element in vector
    int capacity;               //maximum number of element vector can hold
    void *elems;                //pointer to data memory
    VectorFreeFunction freefn;  //pointer to the function used to free each element
} vector;

/**
 * Reallocate a new memory of twice of original size
 * return 1 if reallocation success, otherwise return -1.
 */
static void DoubleMemory(vector *v) {
    void *tmp = realloc(v->elems, v->capacity * v->elemSize * 2);
    assert(tmp != NULL);
    v->elems = tmp;
    v->capacity *= 2;
}

/**
 * Constructor
 */
void VectorNew(vector *v, int elemSize, VectorFreeFunction freefn, int initialAllocation) {
    v->elems = malloc(initialAllocation * elemSize);
    assert(v->elems != NULL);
    v->elemSize = elemSize;
    v->elemNum = 0;
    v->capacity = initialAllocation;
    v->freefn = freefn;
}

/**
 * Frees up all the memory of the specified vector.
 */
void VectorDispose(vector *v) {
    if (v->freefn != NULL) {
        for (; v->elemNum > 0; v->elemNum--) {
            void *elemAddr = (char *)v->elems + (v->elemNum - 1) * v->elemSize;
            v->freefn(elemAddr);
        }
    }
    free(v->elems);
    v->elems = NULL;
}

/**
 * Returns the logical length of the vector.
 */
int VectorLength(const vector *v) {
    return v->elemNum;  
}

/**
 * Appends a new element to the end of the specified vector.
 */
void VectorAppend(vector *v, const void *elemAddr) {
    /* double size if neccessary */
    if (v->elemNum == v->capacity) DoubleMemory(v);
    memcpy((char *)v->elems + v->elemNum * v->elemSize, elemAddr, v->elemSize);
    v->elemNum++;
}

/**
 * Search the specified vector for an element whose contents match the element passed as the key.
 */
int VectorSearch(const vector *v, const void *key, VectorCompareFunction searchfn, int startIndex, bool isSorted) {
    assert(key && searchfn);
    if (v->elemNum == 0) return -1;
    assert(startIndex >= 0 && startIndex < v->elemNum);
    if (isSorted == true) {
        /* binary search */
        void *startAddr = (char *)v->elems + startIndex * v->elemSize;
        int size = v->elemNum - startIndex;
        void *resAddr = bsearch(key, startAddr, size, v->elemSize, searchfn);
        return (resAddr != NULL)? ((char *)resAddr - (char *)v->elems) / v->elemSize : -1;
    } else {
        /* linear search */
        for (int i = 0; i < v->elemNum; i++) {
            if (searchfn((char *)v->elems + i * v->elemSize, key) == 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

#endif // _VECTOR_



/* ============================= TOKENIZER =============================== */

/**
 * Dump current string into vector as a new word.
 * Strings are null-terminated.
 */
static void dumpstack(stack *s, vector *v) {
    size_t len = stack_size(s);
    char *word = (char *)malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char)); // +1 for null-terminator
    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         pop_stack(s, word + i * sizeof(char));
    }
    word[len] = '\0';
    VectorAppend(v, &word);
    clear_stack(s);
}

static const size_t kTokenStackDefaultSize = 64;
static void tokenize(vector *words, char *stream) {
    stack s;
    new_stack(&s, kTokenStackDefaultSize, sizeof(char), NULL);
    size_t len = strlen(stream);
    bool begin = false;
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        c = stream[i];
/* =============================== My printf() is here ============================== */

// printf("char c = [%c]\n", c);

/* =============================== My printf() is here ============================== */
        if (isalpha(c) || isdigit(c)) {
            if (begin == false) begin = true;
            char lower = tolower(c);
            push_stack(&s, &lower, sizeof(char));
        } else if (c == '-') {
            if (begin == true) { // case: covid-19
                push_stack(&s, &c, sizeof(char));
            } else {
                if (i < len - 1 && isdigit(stream[i + 1])) { // case: -9
                    begin = true;
                    push_stack(&s, &c, sizeof(char));
                } else {
                    if (begin == true) {
                        dumpstack(&s, words);
                        begin = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (c == '.' && begin == true) { // case: 3.14
            if (isdigit(stream[i - 1])) {
                push_stack(&s, &c, sizeof(char));
            } else {
                if (begin == true) {
                    dumpstack(&s, words);
                    begin = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (begin == true) {
                dumpstack(&s, words);
                begin = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (begin == true) {
        dumpstack(&s, words);
        begin = false;
    }
    dispose_stack(&s);
}



/* ============================= UNIT-TEST =============================== */

/**
 * HashSetFreeFunction<char *>
 */
static void freestr(void *elemAddr) {
    char *str = *(char **)elemAddr;
    free(str);
}

/**
 * HashSetCompareFunction<char *>
 */
static int compstr(const void *elemAddr1, const void *elemAddr2) {
    char *str1 = *(char **)elemAddr1;
    char *str2 = *(char **)elemAddr2;
    return strcmp(str1, str2);
}

static void test_tokenize(void) {
    printf("Testing Tokenizer.c::tokenize() ...\n");
    char *sentence = "Covid-19: Top adviser warns France at 'emergency' virus moment - BBC News\nPi = 3.14\n-1 is negative.";
    vector words;
    VectorNew(&words, sizeof(char *), freestr, 256);
    tokenize(&words, sentence);
    char *musthave[] = {"covid-19", "top", "3.14", "-1"};
    char *musthavenot[] = {"-", "1"};
    assert(VectorLength(&words) == 16);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(musthave)/sizeof(char *); i++) {
        assert(VectorSearch(&words, &musthave[i], compstr, 0, false) != -1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(musthavenot)/sizeof(char *); i++) {
        assert(VectorSearch(&words, &musthavenot[i], compstr, 0, false) == -1);
    }
    VectorDispose(&words);
    printf("[ALL PASS]\n");
}

int main(void) {
    test_tokenize();
}
```

I've got `segmentation fault` at first.

```
[1]    4685 segmentation fault  testtokenizer
```

**But when I add a `printf()` to debug, the `segmentation fault` was gone** and the test passed. After comment out the `printf`, the function still works. I was so confused.

Just recall that before this test, I tested some memory dispose function, and perhaps had left some unfreed blocks in memory. Will that be the reason for fleeting segmentation fault? Thx bros.

UPDATE:
Now I can't even reproduce this bug myself. `tokenizer.c` above can pass the unit-test. I thought it might caused by makefile prerequisite rules. gcc didn't re-compile some object files when source code is changed.

Thanks @Steve Summit, you make it clear that unfreed memory will not cause segmentation fault.
Thanks @schwern for code review, it's really helpful.

Comment: No, forgetting to free memory will not (by itself) cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: @SteveSummit So forgetting to free memory will just prevent system to reallocate that block of memory? Am I right? thx for quick response.

Comment: Run your program in a debugger to find out at which location the segmentation fault occurs. Your code is incomplete, so I cannot check it. Please create a [mre].

Comment: thx @Bodo. I thought it might caused by `makefile` prerequisite rules. `gcc` didn't re-compile some object files when source codes changed. I can't even reproduce it myself.

Comment: Tools like valgrind and AddressSanitizer will add more checking so that such bugs will crash reliably instead of unpredictably.  Check them out!

Comment: It's completely normal in C for unrelated changes to mask the effects of bugs, e.g. by changing memory layout so that an invalid memory access now overwrites something that doesn't happen to be in use.  But the bug isn't gone until you have understood the root cause and implemented a fix that addresses it at that level.  So start reverting changes until you can reproduce it again, or adopt tools that will help you do so.  Otherwise it will surely reappear at the most inconvenient and harmful possible moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I add a printf() to debug, the segmentation fault was gone and the test passed. After comment out the printf, the function still works. I was so confused.

They call it [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because its behavior is undefined. Seemingly unrelated operations might nudge things just a bit to make the code "work" but they're only tangentially related to the problem.

> I tested some memory dispose function, and perhaps had left some unfreed blocks in memory. Will that be the reason for fleeting segmentation fault?

No. It does mean the memory is unreferencable and ["leaked"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). The memory will be freed to the operating system when the process exits.

The problem must lie elsewhere. Without seeing your whole program we can't say for sure, but two fishy things stand out.

You're defining a fixed sized stack, but you're pushing onto it an indeterminate number of times. Unless `push_stack` has protection against this, you will walk off your allocated memory.

You're storing references to variables on the stack. `lower`, `c`

```
char lower = tolower(c);
push_stack(&s, &lower, sizeof(char));
```

Once `lower` goes out of scope it will automatically be freed and the memory reused. `&lower` is invalid once `tokenize` returns. This seems to be fine if your stack only lasts the length of the function, but it's worth noting.

And it's possible `new_stack`, `push_stack`, or `dumpstack` are doing something incorrect.

Comment: Thx @Schwern for the code review. 1. the stack will call `realloc()` to double its size. 2. my stack has `malloc()` some spaces and will make a copy of each element with `memcpy()`, so the data will not be lost. But still, your suggestions are very useful. It makes me rethink a lot.